# Eclipse: Is there a way to diff a jar and a project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a .jar file that represents a plugin that I am trying to mess with.  This is an older version of the plugin, and a newer version was written by somebody else.  I have this newer version as a project.

The newer project is full of .java files, and the old plugin is full of .class files.  I can import the jar as a project, but it's still all class files.  The differences between the class files and the java files are not particularly large, and I would like to see the differences between them.  When I do this now, however, the text comparison changes the .class file from its normal representation in the editor to a binary representation.  I know that if they were the same type of file, I could select the two and hit "Compare With".  How can I do this between a .class and a .java file, or how can I turn one into the other in a way that still allows me to compare the two?

What would really be best is if there were some way for me to edit the jar, by turning the .class files into .java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it was a plugin, I was able to import it as a plug-in project, and there was a box to include the source folder.  When I checked that I got access to the .java code and was able to diff successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you will need is a decompiler to convert the Java .class files (bytecode) back into their original .java source files (text).  Then you could compare to the two text files.  This seems like it might be useful: http://java.decompiler.free.fr

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable about compilers, but wouldn't decompiling it result in different source code because of compiler optimizations?

Comment: Yes, sometimes decompilation will not produce the exact original source code.  Perhaps it is sufficient for the type of diff you are doing?  You certainly cannot diff the bytecode against the source files as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOOT (http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) to do this. Two approaches are possible:

1. Decompile the .class files into .java files using Dava in SOOT, and then compare the .java files.
2. Convert both .class and .java files into an intermediate representation called Jimple in SOOT, and compare the Jimple files.

I think the second approach is more reasonable, because:

1. In the first approach, some Java files are manually developed, while the others are machine generated. Doing a diff on them creates results that are difficult to read.
2. The Jimple representation is very close to Java source code and relatively easy to read. Reading a diff result on this unified, machine generated format is much easier. Also, if you want, you can convert all Jimple files back to Java source code (well, this is sort of the third approach...).